# Export/Import Django project settings in PyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

Actually I have project with about 20 settings (Django server, Django tests, fabric tasks). Now I want to move my environment to other computer.

Is it possible to migrate all these configurations or should I create manually one by one in new PyCharm instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. What you need to do, is copy *everything* in your project directory, including `.idea` folder, and pasting it to the new place that you want to place it.

Now, all you have to do is open the directory as a project using PyCharm in your new workstation.